# Google Cloud Platform - Dataflow Unable to write to error table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Very new to the world of Google Cloud and even more so to Dataflow.  I am receiving the following error message when trying to write out records which failed to write to my desired Big Query table.

```
Access Denied: Table <project id>:<dataset name>._err_emp: User does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table b <project id>:<dataset name>._err_emp.
```

Obviously this will be a permissions issue, but I don't know where to start when it comes to attempting to resolve it.

I have tried explicitly stating the name of the table, as well as using the default table and the same outcome is obtained.

Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.
Scott

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with your Dataflow pipeline, but with your configured permissions in your GCP Project. The role you're using to run the pipeline lacks permission to get data from your BigQuery table.

If you follow the [Cloud Dataflow Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts) instructions, one of the steps is to set up a service account for running your job and give it the "Owner" role. This role should be broad enough to provide access to nearly everything in your project, so it should fix your problem. If you already followed that step in the quickstart and are still having the issue, chances are it's a configuration problem, most likely a problem with getting the correct key identified.

For an in-depth understanding of the IAM system, I recommend first reading through some of the basic documentation for GCP's [IAM system](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/) followed by taking a look at the guide on [BigQuery Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) if you want more details for BigQuery specifically.

Comment: thank you for that information.  I should have included in the OP that I am using a template, so I didn't need to set up a service account.  Unless I am mistaken.  I will however, create a new service account with the permissions you suggested.